# Is it possible to obtain the address of the next instruction to execute using EPROCESS structure?

Tags: c, windows, multithreading, data-structures, process

I would like to know if it is possible to obtain the address of the next instruction which is to be executed of the currently executing thread ? Let's suppose that I have a pointer to an EPROCESS object (of the currently executing thread) is it then possible to obtain the address of the very next instruction to execute regardless if the machine is multi-core or single core.

Comment: Would you mind to detail a bit on your scenario? Since executing a statement is executing one or more instructions, which one is the next instruction?

Comment: are you looking for the REAL hardware address or the virtual address?

Comment: @user3629249 looking for real hardware address. Thanks.

Comment: @busybee the order of each instruction to execute does matter. The application that I'm working on does require the REAL address of the next instruction to execute. How can I ensure that my code is executing next instruction as it was meant to ?